# Waters into Canada

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

I have seen this sentence in The Globalization of World Politics:

> Waters off the coast of Alaska and into Canada have turned into a navigable ocean.

I am a bit confused as to what "into" in "into Canada" means.

Answer (score 1):

This is the second quotation from this book that I have seen asked about in the last few days. Although this one is not so egregiously awful as the first I saw, it is still not clear writing.

"Waters" is being used here in one of three senses: (a) a body of water such as a sea, lake, pond, river, or creak, (b) such a body of water over which a state is generally considered to have legal jurisdiction, or (c) that part of the sea over which a state claims legal jurisdiction. Notice that sense (a) is seldom used to refer to the oceans as a whole or even to a single ocean, but it may be on occasion, e.g., "Atlantic waters" as a synonym for "Atlantic ocean." In any case, which sense is being used is unclear: the reference to "navigable" seems to imply a body of water, but the reference to Canada and Alaska seems to refer to concepts of international law.

Strictly speaking, "waters ... have turned into ... oceans" makes no sense at all. The Yukon River has not turned into an ocean. Nor can an ocean or any part of an ocean turn into an ocean. Nor is "navigable ocean" a meaningful concept because even the frozen Arctic Ocean is navigable in part during the summer months as any Inuit knows. And finally U.S. waters are not turning into Canadian waters or vice versa: Trump has not declared Churchill, Manitoba, as a U. S. port, nor is Trudeau laying claim to the waters containg bonefish off Florida.

Now, as in the last quotation from this book that I saw, context may make the virtually nonsensical reasonably clear. Absent that context, my guess as to what is meant is

> The Arctic Ocean north of the coasts of Canada and Alaska has become a commercially significant sea lane.

Whether that is a true statement, I do not know, but it is an intelligible and perhaps even plausible statement. Whether some such meaning was intended only the gods may divine. Perhaps what is being asserted is that Great Slave Lake has become part of the Pacific Ocean by connecting with the Bering Strait through the Seward Peninsula and that the resulting barge traffic between western Alaska and the interior of Canada is growing exponentially. That too is an intelligible statement but not one I find particularly plausible.

The reason that bad writing is bad is because what is intended cannot be easily and unambiguously understood.

Comment: I interpreted this to be a reference to climate change, implying that most or all sea ice has disappeared in the area around Alaska and in the Beaufort Sea. "Navigable" would then mean usable by marine traffic without special measures like icebreakers. I agree it could be written better.

Comment: @TypeA Your guess is as good as mine. As the title of the book implies, and as the previous quotation I saw validates, the book's topic is politics, not necessarily meteorology. The title of the book, moreover,, indicates that the author **desperately** needed a good editor. Is it even conceivable that world politics could be other than global?

Comment: @TypeIA Furthermore our individual best guesses do not differ that much. It probably does refer to greater use of the Arctic as a feasible route for marine traffic for **whatever** reason or reasons, but a writer with any semblance of competence could find a way to say that clearly. It is not an extremely complex thought.

Comment: I agree with @TypeIA – you say, "waters ... have turned into ... oceans" makes no sense at all, but I think the key word (that makes it sensible) is _navigable_.

Comment: @TypelA you are correct. The sentences preceding that sentence are "Yet, all its members are well aware of the potential security challegens presented by an Arctic shaw. In a single day in August 2010, the US Coast Guard detected ninety-five ships in the Northwest Passage area near Alaska." They (the authors) are saying that because of ice melting, the ocean is now open for sailing. However, I was not talking about the second into. I was talking about the first into. Sorry for causing misunderstanding.